# Erro no código da calculadora programada em Java

Tags: java

A mensagem de erro é esta: não é possível encontrar o símbolo símbolo: método gettext () localização: variável txttela do tipo JTextField São vários erros, mas é o mesmo.O que entendo é que falta criar o método gettext () e o settext () na variável txttela do tipo jtextfield, porém não estou conseguindo fazer, alguém pode respoder por genteleza.

A mensagem de erro é esta:

> ```
> cannot find symbol
> symbol: methodgettext()
> location: variable txttela of type jtextfield
> ```

o código é este:

```
private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String corrente;
        corrente = txttela.getText();

        if (corrente.length() <= 0) {
            txttela.setText("0.");

    }                                         
        else {
            if (!existeponto(txttela.gettext())) {
                txttela.settext(txttela.gettext() + ".");
            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean existeponto(String corrente) {
        boolean resultado;
        resultado = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < corrente.length(); i++) {
            if (corrente.substring(i, i + 1).equals(".")) {
                resultado = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        return resultado;

    }

    private void jButton20ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String corrente;
        corrente = txttela.gettext();

        if (corrente.length() > 0) {
            corrente = corrente.substring(0, corrente.length() - 1);
            txttela.settext(corrente);
        }
    }                                         

    private void jButton17ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        txttela.settext("");

    }                                         

    private void jButton18ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String corrente;
        Double num;
        corrente = txttela.gettext();
        if (corrente.length() > 0) {
            num = 1 / (Double.parseDouble(corrente));
            txttela.settext(num.toString());
        }
    }                                         

    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Double num;
        String corrente;

        corrente = txttela.gettext();
        if (corrente.length() > 0);
        {
            num = (-1) * Double.parseDouble(corrente);
            txttela.settext(num.toString());
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton16ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        if (!txttela.gettext().equals("")) {
            memoria1 = txttela.gettext();
            signo = "-";
            txttela.settext("");
        }
    }                                         

    private void jButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (!txttela.gettext().equals("")) {
            memoria1 = txttela.gettext();
            signo = "+";
            txttela.settext("");
        }
    }                                         

    private void jButton14ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (!txttela.gettext().equals("")) {
            memoria1 = txttela.gettext();
            signo = "*";
            txttela.settext("");
        }
    }                                         

    private void jButton15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (!txttela.gettext().equals("")) {
            memoria1 = txttela.gettext();
            signo = "/";
            txttela.settext("");
        }
    }                                         

    private void jButton19ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String resultado;
        memoria2 = txttela.gettext();

        if (!memoria2.equals("")) {
            resultado = calculadora(memoria1, memoria2, signo);
            txttela.settext(resultado);
        }
    }                                         

    private void txttelaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        setText("String");
        gettext();// TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente mudar gettext() para getText()

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente foi um erro de digitação seu, o método correto é `getText();` e você usou `gettext();` com letra minúscula.